# Browser add on/extension to intercept data selection then simulate link click and data entry

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, add-in

Background: a third party web application with a requirement on the order page to explicitly guide staff when a certain category of product is ordered.

Normal process:

- select product to add order line (click on product image)

New process:

- select product to add order line (click on product image)
- [add on] simulate click on edit order line
- [add on] simulate clear of default additional information form fields
- enter additional information and click save

Note that the two steps to be performed by the add-on could be performed by the user however when things get busy or new staff begin is often the case that the order gets processed with the default value.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.
A multi-browser solution is preferred but not essential.

I am an experienced developer, including web development, but have no experience in browser add on/extension development.

Thanks.

Comment: Looking at Greasemonkey which might be a Firefox option...

Answer (score 0):

You can make an addon out of this very easily. You addEventListener to the gBrowser and if the event.target is the product element then preventDefault so the click doesnt go thru (you will have to do mousedown and mouseup prevent as well). Then rather get the id of the "edit order line" and do `.click()` if that doesnt work and you really need to simulate use `MouseEvent`:

[MDN :: MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMouseEvent)

[MDN :: Initatite/Dispatch MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initMouseEvent)

To enter aditional information get the id of the fields, and set their value. Then get the "Save" button id and then do `.submit()` or `.click()`

i said do get id in this post but you can use `querySelector` and go by css selector

see this page here on how to interact with content in currently selected tab:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser

basically just do `gBrowser.contentDocument.getElementById`

Comment: Do you mean this gBrowser - http://gbrowser.sourceforge.net/?  It appears to be Linux only.

Comment: No dude clik on  that mdn link, tabbed browser, use that gBrowser